# Seeding rails databases in a service oriented environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, soa

Bit of a thought exercise regarding seeding databases of rails apps across several services.

## Setup

For example, consider a super simplified example consisting of 4 services (rails apps) which communicate via client gems and each expose a basic API.

```
AuthService - (user_id, password)

PropertyService (user_id, property_id, address)

UserService (user_id, user_info)

MortgageService - (property_id, mortgage_id, current_cost_of_mortgage)
```

Basically a user has many properties and each has a mortgage. Simple enough.

Each service also has a client with sightly restricted access as to which fields it can access. Hence it isn't very feasible as a mechanism for populating it's service (unless you disaggree?).

## Question

When seeding this as a whole, you obviously want any user you refer to in the property service to also exist in the auth service and similarly for the other service relationships.

What would be the best way of seeding these services with sample data such that they all matched up?

## Potential Methods Considered

1. Create hard fixtures for each service
2. Create a database dump for each service and just directly import it
3. Use Factory Girl and somehow figure out how to sync the ids

Factory girl would be nicest as it would let me change the data which is seeded fairly easily and add more/less data without issue. I just can't wrap my head around how to do it...

Any questions just shoot, really interested to hear if anyone is doing something like this or has tried it and how they're managing it!

Comment: "you obviously want any user you refer to in the property service to also exist in the auth service" - This seems like something you should break out into it's own service, a `UserService` if you will. Having to sync IDs between duplicated data stores is a warning sign to me.

Comment: Sorry, I perhaps wasn't very clear. Have updated my example, can you take another look? The id's are necessary to, for example, make a call to the property service to get all property for a user?